# How to start a multiple flows that can be "switched off" when not needed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

#### Scenario

1. `List<Message>` in a composable
2. `messages = mutableStateListOf<Message>` in viewModel
3. `messages` depends on two actions `getAll` or `search`
4. In both cases we observe SQLite, but **only one flow should be active at a single instant** (user is either viewing all or is searching)
5. Flow is used with SQLite because new messages can come from the network.

#### Questions

1. How to switch between `getAll`  and `search`  flow
2. When a new search happens the old `search` flow should be cancelled and a new one should start. How to do this?

**Current implementation with two flows**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListOfMessages() {
    val messages = viewModel.messages
}

// -----------------------------
// ViewModel
// -----------------------------
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MessageViewModel(application: Application) {
    val messages = mutableStateListOf<Message>()
    val isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        fetchMessages()
    }

    fun fetchMessages() {
        MessageUseCase(messagesDB).getAll().onEach { dataState ->
            isLoading.value = dataState.loading
            
            dataState.data?.let { data ->
                messages.clear()
                messages.addAll(data)
            }

            dataState.error?.let { error ->
                // UIState -> error message
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun SearchWithInMessage(q: String) {
        MessageUseCase(messagesDB).search(q).onEach { dataState ->
            isLoading.value = dataState.loading
            
            dataState.data?.let { data ->
                messages.clear()
                messages.addAll(data)
            }

            dataState.error?.let { error ->
                // UIState -> error message
            }
        }
    }
}

// -----------------------------
// Use Cases
// -----------------------------
class MessageUseCase(messagesDB: messageDao) {
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun getAll(): Flow<DataState<List<Message>>> = channelFlow { {
        send(DataState.loading())

        try {
            fetchAndSaveLatestMessagesFromRemote()
            val messages = messagesDB.getAllStream()
            messages.collectLatest { list ->
                // business logic
                send(DataState.success(list))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            send(DataState.error<List<Message>>(e.message?: "Unknown Error"))
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun search(q: String): Flow<DataState<List<Message>>> = channelFlow { {
        send(DataState.loading())

        try {
            fetchAndSaveSearchedMessageFromRemote(q)
            val messages = messagesDB.searchStream(q)
            messages.collectLatest { list ->
                // business logic
                send(DataState.success(list))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception){
            send(DataState.error<List<Message>>(e.message?: "Unknown Error"))
        }
    }
}

// -----------------------------
// DB and Network calls
// -----------------------------
```

Comment: For the second part, you need not worry about cancelling flow. If you stop collecting from a (cold) flow, it consumes no resources. For your first question, add some code in the question showing how the `getAll` and `search` flows are being generated.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Added some bare minimum code

Comment: Btw, if you search for an empty string, does it give a different result than fetching all data? Because if it doesn't you can convert your `messagesDB.getAllStream()` to `messagesDB.searchStream("")`, which will simplify the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [flatMapLatest()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html). It receives a flow of flows and always replicate items of the latest flow sent to it, cancelling previous flow. As a result, it works as the flow that can switch between other flows.

Depending on how your `getAll()` and `search()` are declared, it could be something like this:

```kotlin
private val state = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
private val messages = state.flatMapLatest {
    if (it == null) getAll() else search(it)
}

suspend fun requestSearch(search: String) = state.emit(search)
suspend fun requestAll() = state.emit(null)

fun getAll(): Flow<List<Message>> = TODO()
fun search(search: String): Flow<List<Message>> = TODO()
```

`state` represents our currently required search state. Whenever we emit to it, it requests either `getAll()` or `search()` flow and replicates it as `messages` flow.

Then, to use it with Compose, you need to convert it to `State`:

```kotlin
messages.collectAsState(emptyList())
```

Comment: Kotlin Flow APIs are so hard to be searched on the internet. How did you learn these? By facing a need and exploring or reading the docs even before a need occured.

Comment: I don't really remember, but once I went through all functions in the left sidebar on the website linked by me above - just for curiosity. It seems like a lot of stuff, but it could be done in an hour or so and then we have at least an insight on what is possible. Also, `flatMapLatest()` is a very specific function, it is very often compared to `switchMap` operator of RxJava.

Comment: @clmno `flatMap` is a pretty classic name for this kind of operation on collections/sequences/streams in general, only the details of cancellation are particular to `Flow` here. So in my case the first time I needed it I just tried `flatMap` and read the docs of whatever function name was auto-completed here :D But I also believe I did go through the whole list once, just out of curiosity like broot